# Using str.replace gives me a TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Tags: python, string, integer

I have a homework about making a phone book. And I did a code.

```
import sys
print("Type 'help' to learn commands ") 
command = ("show_list, add_person, delete_person, search_person, exit") 

command1 = ()
list1 = {}

while True:
command1 = input("Command: ")
saved = open("PhoneBook.txt", "a")

if command1 == "help":
    print(command)
    print()

elif command1 == "show_list":
    saved = open("PhoneBook.txt", "r")
    print(saved.read())
    saved.close()

elif command1 == "add_person":
    name = str(input("Name: "))
    number = int(input("Number: "))
    list1[name] = number
    saved = open("PhoneBook.txt", "w") 
    saved.write("\n-------------")
    saved.write(str(name))
    saved.write(":")
    saved.write(str(number))
    saved.write("-------------\n")
    saved.close()

elif command1 == "search_person":
    search = open("PhoneBook.txt", "r")
    search1 = input("Name:")
    for line in search:
        if search1 in line:
            print("\n")
            print(search)

elif command1 == "delete_person":
    del0 = open("PhoneBook.txt", "r+")
    del1 = str(input("Name: "))
    for line in del0:
        if del1 in line:
            del2 = line.replace(" ", " ", " ")
            del0.write(silinecek3)
            del0.close()

elif command1 == "exit":
    sys.exit()`
```

And everything is good (I think), except deleting a name. Because when I try to delete a name, it gives me an output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/oyuni/Desktop/ödeving.py", line 47, in <module>
    del2 = line.replace(" ", " ", " ")
TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

And I don't know what to do. Can anyone help me to fix the code?

Comment: What do you expect `line.replace(" ", " ", " ")` to do? `replace`'s 3rd argument should be an `int`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`str.replace()` can take either 2 or 3 arguments, but that 3rd argument *must* be an integer (it limits the number of replacements that take place).

You passed in a string as the third argument:

```
line.replace(" ", " ", " ")
```

Pass in just two strings, and make those different strings if you actually want to replace anything:

```
line.replace(" ", "")
```

However, this won't delete the name. The rest of that block of code is going to give you more problems:

- You didn't define the name `silinecek3`
- You can't safely read and write to the same file, at the same time. Read all of the file into memory first, or write to a new file that then is moved back into place.
- You want to remove names entirely; do so by writing out all names you keep (so filter out the lines, write each one that doesn't have the name).